# Changing value attribute of radio buttons in a group using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have multiple dynamically added radio buttons. I want to change the value attribute of selected radio button to `"yes"` and change the radio button value to `"no"` once some other radio button is selected.

```
<input type="radio" name="tab-active" value="no" />
```

I am able to get the value to change to `"yes"` by using the following jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click","input[name=tab-active]:radio",function(){
    if($("input:radio[name=tab-active]").is(":checked")) {
        $(this).val('yes');
    }
});
```

How can I change the value attribute of the selected radio button to `"no"` once some other radio button is selected?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector. And, as you see, you also can use :checked to set the value to yes.

```
$(document).on("click","input[name=active]:radio",function(){
    $("input:radio[name=active]:checked").val('yes');
    $("input:radio[name=active]:not(:checked)").val('no');
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7hk56/)

Comment: +1 for efficiency and for introducing me to the `:not()` selector.

Answer (score 1):

Another way,

```
$(document).on("click","input[name=tab-active]:radio",function(){
    $("input:radio[name=tab-active]:not(:checked)").val('no');
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).val('yes');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wcxRV/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can make html tags like

```
<input type="radio" id="1" name="tab-active"  /><span id="lbl1">no</span>
<input type="radio" id="2" name="tab-active" /><span id="lbl2">no</span>
<input type="radio" id="3" name="tab-active"  /><span id="lbl3">no</span>
```

And the js code like

```
$(document).on("click","input[type:radio]",function(){    
    if($("input:radio[name=tab-active]").is(":checked")) {
       $("#lbl" + $(this).attr('id')).html("yes");   
    }
});
```

You can check it in this link http://jsfiddle.net/nkvak/

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name='tab-active']").change(function()
    {
        $("input[name='tab-active']").val('no');
        $(this).val('yes');
    }
)
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3mvKt/2/)**